# Why is my list specifically the last item of the list not going through the iteration (or not seen in output)?

Tags: python

I'm (a Newb) trying to iterate over a long list however the function that I have written will not iterate over the entire list, why?

This is for a program that will take the list input and search google looking for relevant websites and return those website links to me in the form of a list. Using Python 3

```
import logging
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from googlesearch import search


def get_urls(tag, n, language):
    urls = [url for url in search(tag, stop=n, lang=language)][:n]
    return urls
```

`my_list = [['Apples'], ['Oranges'], ['Pears']]`

```
flat_list = []
for sublist in my_list:
    for item in sublist:
        flat_list.append(item)

i = 0 
sizeofList = len(flat_list)
while i < sizeofList:
    print(flat_list[i])
    i+=1

def w_next(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    current = next(iterator)
    for next_item in iterator:
        yield current, next_item
        current = next_item

myResults=[]
def look(*args):
    for i, next_item in w_next(args):
            if sizeofList > 0:
                myResults.append(get_urls(i, 2, 'en'))
            else:
                return "".join(myResults)

    print (myResults)


look(*flat_list)
```

Actual Output:

```
[['apples.com', 'yummyapples.com'], ['oranges.com', 'yummyoranges.com']]
```

Expected Output:

```
[['apples.com', 'yummyapples.com'], ['oranges.com', 'yummyoranges.com'], ['pears.com', 'yummypears.com']}
```

I just wanted it to iterate over the entire list but why won't it?

Comment: What is `get_urls()`? See [mcve].

Comment: You don't do anything with `next_item`. That'll be the variable that holds the last element of the list.

Comment: Call `myResults.append(get_urls(next_item, 2, 'en'))` just berore `print (myResults)` to handle the last item left.

Comment: Thank you Andej that seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def w_next(iterable):
...     iterator = iter(iterable)
...     current = next(iterator)
...     for next_item in iterator:
...         print(current, next_item)
...         current = next_item
... 
>>> w_next(['apple', 'pear', 'orange'])
apple pear
pear orange
```

You have an off-by-one error in `w_next`. The last item in the list will never show up. The whole thing could be made a lot easier:

```
>>> def w_next(my_list):
...     for item in my_list:
...         print(item)
... 
>>> w_next(['apple', 'pear', 'orange'])
apple
pear
orange
>>>
```

Note that for the sake of simplicity I replaced your `yield` with `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `next_item` in your `w_next`? Simply do

```
>>> def w_next(iterable):
...     iterator = iter(iterable)
...     for current in iterator:
...         yield current
```

That will do. For your answer, since the last item in the loop is returned as a tuple, and is unpacked in line `for i, next_item in w_next(args):`. You call functions on `i`, but the last item is in `next_item` and is never dealt with.